# how to convert triplets to RDF triplets?

Tags: rdf, spacy, knowledge-graph

I was able to get a set of triplets from the following text: "Christian Drosten works in Germany. Christian Drosten likes to work for Google."

```
{'relation': 'country of citizenship', 'head_span': {'text': 'Christian Drosten', 'id': 'Q1079331'}, 'tail_span': {'text': 'Germany', 'id': 'Q183'}}
471a35571b66cc8e1e3415e27f7086505310efc6: {'relation': 'employer', 'head_span': {'text': 'Christian Drosten', 'id': 'Q1079331'}, 'tail_span': {'text': 'Google', 'id': 'Q9366'}}
```

now I am looking how to convert these triplets to RDF triplets and add them to a knowledge graph.

Can someone give me a suggestion on the steps to do? and if there are any frameworks that can do the job?

Comment: **How** did you "*get a set of triplets from the foloowing text*"? What does `head_span` and `tail_span` mean? Where does the `id` come from?

Comment: using spacy and import crosslingual_coreference. head_span means the subject and tail_span means the object where I get its id from wikidata

Comment: If you have wikidata ids for subject and object, it's trivial to build an URI for those. But for the predicate, it's not clear what you want to generate.

Comment: I dont have and wikidata's id for every extracted subject and object, So im looking for a suggestion to how what must i do to create such ids?

Comment: "create" IDs is what Spacy does for you already if it finds those - this process is called *entity linking* and non-trivial. The questions is more, what if there is no such entity in Wikidata? Moreover, the relations might also not be contained in Wikidata ontology, so in the long-term you have to generate your own entitiy URIs and properties for your KG anyways. Long story short, create your own entities and your own properties based on the extracted tokens from Spacy, especially if there hasn't been found a Wikidata entity